# How to detect if a Label contains the same elements as a String(In any orders) - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, string, uilabel

I'd like to detect with a `if` condition when a label contains all the same elements (in any order) of a 'String'.

Here's an example of my program:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
var word: String = "house"
label.text = "ouhse"
```

It is at this point that I am stuck. How can I detect if the text of `label` contains the same letters as `word`?

What I want is a way to know if ‘label’ contains the same letters (and the same amount of letters) as ‘word’ without it being necessarily in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

Unclear exactly what the requirements are. Here's an easy way to see if two strings are "all the same letters" in a fairly broad sense:

```
let s1 = "house"
let s2 = "ouhse"
s1.sorted() == s2.sorted() // true
```

But that might not cover what you really want to do (because you didn't enunciate clearly what that might be). For example, this tests "all the same letters" in a somewhat different sense:

```
let s1 = "yoho"
let s2 = "hoy"
Set(s1) == Set(s2) // true
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I realize that, indeed, I did not enunciate clearly what I wanted to know:

What I want is a way to know if ‘label’ contains the same letters(And the same amount of letters) as ‘word’ without It being necessarily in the same order.

Thank you,

Unknown_